# Customized Chart In Anylogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

Hi I am working on production model, where I have set of 5 service blocks.My model is running for one shift a day ( from 8:00 AM to 4:30PM). I am using time plot to track the daily number of final goods produce. But since we don't have the hover over option for the graphs it is very difficult to understand the exact day and quantity produce. How can I create a day wise bar graph in Anylogic. [Present output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIfoN.png)
PS : I tried to upload the photo but it is coming the form of link.

2nd: I want to change the steps x-axis in histogram, and if there is option to include the hover-over so how can we do that.
[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jxeL.png)

Comment: Hi Harsh, please split your question into two questions. Having multiple questions in one not only makes it difficult for future askers to find questions and answers applicable to their query but also makes it more work to answer the question. 
Also be sure to check out the standard AnyLogic help first

Histogram: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/analysis/histogram.html#histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is theoretically possible to make a day-wise bar chart it is not advised since every day will need to be a value in your chart, you can do this by using `chart.addDataItem(DataItem)` on a bar chart.
[image]

You will then need to create a new data item for every day and and it to the chart every day

```
DataItem di = new DataItem();
di.setValue(10);
barChart.addDataItem(di, "Day x", barColor);
```

If it is just the visual effect you are after I would suggest using a line chart but changing interpolation to steps and coloring the area under the curve.

I will look more or less like a bar chart.

[image]

[image]